# Angular @ngrx/store dispatch method concatenates an object property with itself

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework, angular5, ngrx-store

The app is written using Ionic. I have a shopping cart where i'm adding products. The product is an object with a note and quantity property. After i use the `this.store.dispatch(new PushProductAction({ product }));` the note property is concatenated with itself, i.e. i'm adding 3 products to cart with a note 'cold', in the cart this product will have the note property equal to 'coldcoldcold'.

app-state.ts

```
export class AppState {
  categories: Category[];
  shopcart: ShopCart;
  profile: Profile;
  userdata: UserData;
}
```

product-info.ts

```
constructor(
        private events: Events,
        public store: Store<AppState>,
}

pushToCart(product: Product) {
        product.quantity = product.quantity ? ++product.quantity : 1;
        product.withHalf = this.halfProductStatus;
        this.store.dispatch(new PushProductAction({ product }));
}
```

After the product is added :

```
goToConfirm(event, desktop = false) {
        event.preventDefault();
        event.stopPropagation();
        jQuery.fancybox.close();
        jQuery('.fancybox-close-small').trigger('click');

        for (let index = 0; index < this.count; index++) {
            this.pushToCart(this.product);
        }
        this.fixDesign.CreateToast('Product has been added to cart successfuly', 'successToast');

}
```

actions.ts

```
export class PushProductAction implements Action {
  readonly type = ActionTypes.PUSH_CART;
  constructor(public payload: { product: Product; half?: boolean }) {
    console.log('PushProductAction');
  }
}
```

P.S. I'm a beginner in angular, if you need more code snippets please let me know.

Comment: where is note set?

Comment: It is in the product.model.ts. (Product class)